# ANTLR : issue with greedy rule

Tags: parsing, antlr, grammar, lexer

I never worked with ANTLR and generative grammars, so this is my first attempt.

I have a custom language I need to parse.
Here's an example:

```
-- This is a comment
CMD.CMD1:foo_bar_123
CMD.CMD2
CMD.CMD4:9 of 28 (full)
CMD.NOTES:
This is an note.
    A line 
      (1) there could be anything here foo_bar_123 & $ £ _ , . ==> BOOM
      (3) same here
CMD.END_NOTES:
```

Briefly, there could be 4 types of lines:

```
1) -- comment
2) <section>.<command>
3) <section>.<command>: <arg>
4) <section>.<command>:
       <arg1>
       <arg2>
       ...
   <section>.<end_command>:
```

> <section> is the literal "CMD"
>
> <command> is a single word (uppercase, lowercase letters, numbers, '_')
>
> <end_command> is the same word of <command> but preceded by the literal "end_"
>
> <arg> could be any character

Here's what I've done so far:

```
grammar MyGrammar;

/*
* Parser Rules
*/

root                : line+ EOF ;

line                : (comment_line | command_line | normal_line) NEWLINE;

comment_line        : COMMENT ;

command_line        : section '.' command ((COLON WHITESPACE*)? arg)? ;

normal_line         : TEXT ;

section             : CMD ;

command             : WORD ;

arg                 : TEXT ;

/*
* Lexer Rules
*/

fragment LOWERCASE  : [a-z] ;
fragment UPPERCASE  : [A-Z] ;
fragment DIGIT      : [0-9] ;

NUMBER          : DIGIT+ ([.,] DIGIT+)? ;

CMD             : 'CMD';

COLON           : ':' ;

COMMENT         : '--' ~[\r\n]*;

WHITESPACE      : (' ' | '\t') ;

NEWLINE         : ('\r'? '\n' | '\r')+;

WORD            : (LOWERCASE | UPPERCASE | NUMBER | '_')+ ;

TEXT            : ~[\r\n]* ;
```

This is a test for my grammar:

> $antlr4 MyGrammar.g4
>
> warning(146): MyGrammar.g4:45:0: non-fragment lexer rule TEXT can match the empty string
>
> $javac MyGrammar*.java
>
> $grun MyGrammar root -tokens
>
> CMD.NEW
>
> [@0,0:6='CMD.NEW',<TEXT>,1:0]
>
> [@1,7:7='\n',<NEWLINE>,1:7]
>
> [@2,8:7='<EOF>',<EOF>,2:0]

The problem is that "CMD.NEW" gets swallowed by TEXT, because that rule is greedy.

Anyone can help me with this?
Thanks

Comment: How do you define the distinction between argument and a new command? In other words, how can the parser tell that `This is an note.` is part of `CMD.NOTES` and not a new command?

Comment: You've got a point. I forgot to add the corresponding end_command for commands with multiline arguments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a grammar ambiguity.

In the example you have provided `CMD.NEW` can match both `command_line` and `normal_line`.
Thus, given the expression:

```
 line                : (comment_line | command_line | normal_line) NEWLINE;
```

the parser can not definitely say what rule to accept (`command_line` or `normal_line`), so it matches it to `normal_line` which is actually a simple `TEXT`.

Consider rewriting your grammar in the way the parser can always say what rule to accept.

**UPDATE:**

Try this (I did not test that, but it should work):

```
grammar MyGrammar;

/*
* Parser Rules
*/

root                : line+ EOF ;

line                : (comment_line | command_line) NEWLINE;

comment_line        : COMMENT ;

command_line        : CMD '.' (note_cmd | command);

command             : command_name ((COLON WHITESPACE*)? arg)? ;

note_cmd            : notes .*? (CMD '.' END_NOTES) ;

command_name             : WORD ;

arg                 : TEXT ;

/*
* Lexer Rules
*/

fragment LOWERCASE  : [a-z] ;
fragment UPPERCASE  : [A-Z] ;
fragment DIGIT      : [0-9] ;

NUMBER          : DIGIT+ ([.,] DIGIT+)? ;

CMD             : 'CMD';

COLON           : ':' ;

COMMENT         : '--' ~[\r\n]*;

WHITESPACE      : (' ' | '\t') ;

NEWLINE         : ('\r'? '\n' | '\r')+;

WORD            : (LOWERCASE | UPPERCASE | NUMBER | '_')+ ;

NOTES            : 'NOTES';

END_NOTES        : 'END_NOTES';

TEXT            : ~[\r\n]* ;
```

Comment: Yeah, that's the problem. `TEXT` is a greedy rule and ANTLR always tries to match the largest possible token. I need a way to capture everything inside `CMD.NOTES` and `CMD.END_NOTES`.

Comment: Now commands like `CMD.NEW` work fine. I understand what you did there: in order to avoid ambiguity you specified the commands pair which contains free text (everything inside CMD.NOTES and CMD.END_NOTES). The drawback of this approach is that I have to write a rule for every pair.

Comment: The problem has now been moved to lines like `<section>.<command>: <arg>`

Comment: You do not have to write a rule for each pair since 'command_name' is a regex expression. But if you want to have a specific rule for a specific pair (like you do with CMD.NOTES), then yes, you have to provide a rule for that pair.